# How has using THREE.Object3D changed from r52 to r72?

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I have been editing models and grouping them together using `Object3D` in `r52` which works fine. When I change to using `r72` the model loads but in a distorted way and without some elements. I think it might have something to do with the "`Object3D`'s position, rotation, quaternion and scale properties are now immutable." from the change log `r67-r68`.

```
~mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Migration
```

With r52 
http://timepcode.web44.net/invaders-master/ships/saterlite.html

with r72
http://timepcode.web44.net/invaders-master/ships/saterlite72.html

Comment: Distorted? They look the same to me

Comment: My bad, I think I must have change something so they both referenced 54.